# Zigzag Bevel behaviour on a mirror

Tags: bevel

I have a mirrored model with transforms all applied, I get a really weird bevel. A zigzag..

Any thoughts.

[image]

Comment: when you say that it's mirrored, are you talking about the mirror option? I wonder if there's not a bug with this option...

Comment: can you share the blend file?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer the Norms where the different. Ctrl-N fixed it up.